# Whey the applications running in VNC shows up in host instead of in client?

Tags: vnc, debian-buster

When I connect to the vnc server with vncviewer,  I get a stranger thing: I can see the desktop of gnome or xfce4 and their menus,  every GUI application I launch doesn't show up.  At first I thought the applications failed to run.  Then I found the applications appeared in the vnc server's screen!  My settings are:

vncserver:  tigervncserver  on Debian 10

the content of ~/.vnc/xstartup:

unset SESSION_MANAGER

exec /usr/bin/xfce4-session &

vnc client:  xtightvncviewer  on Debian 8

I use the client to connect a vncserver on Ubuntu 18, it works well.  Do you have any suggestion to debug this issue?  Thanks.

Comment: command to run vncserver:  vncserver :1   -localhost no -verbose

Comment: I have the same problem with vncserver on Ubuntu 20.04 and VNC viewer on Windows 10. This happens when the same user is already logged into the vncserver host and had those applications open. For example if a Chrome window is open in the host session, another Chrome window opens in the host session even if the launch command was issued from within the VNC session. Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

On my Ubuntu/XFCE enviroment, on the host device, my DISPLAY env variable is set to :1.0 and not :0 , so when I started a vnc on :1, the applications would pop up on the host display. Just start the vncserver on :2 or above, and the problem will not occur.